# unmarshaling always shows 0 and null

Tags: java, jaxb

I think the best way is to copy my code so you can understand it.

Here are my POJO classes:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Product {

    private String name;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "productName")
    public String getProduct() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="ShoppingCart")

public class Cart {

    private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    private long CartIdentifier;

    public Cart() {

    }
    public Cart(long id) {
        this.CartIdentifier=id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="CartIdentifier")
    public long getId() {
        return  CartIdentifier;
    }

    public void setType(long id) {
        this.CartIdentifier=id;
    }

    public Cart(List<Product> list) {
        this.productList = list;
    }

    public void addElement(Product element) {
        this.productList.add(element);
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "CurrentProducts")
    public List<Product> getCart() {
        return this.productList;
    }

    public void setCart(List<Product> cart) {
        this.productList = cart;
    }

}

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "CashRegister")
public class Register {
    @XmlElement(name = "ShoppingCart")
    private ArrayList<Cart> listCart;

    long CartIdentifier;

    public Register() {

    }

    public Register(long id) {
        this.CartIdentifier=id;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return  CartIdentifier;
    }

    public void addElementforBonus(Cart element) {
        listCart.add(element);
    }

    public void setType(long id) {
        this. CartIdentifier=id;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Cart> list) {
        this.listCart = list;
    }

    public ArrayList<Cart> getCartList() {
        return listCart;
    }

}
```

So those are my POJO classes and in main they create perfect XML, but when it comes to converting from XML to normal output something goes wrong. Can someone tell me where am I making mistake and why is my output than alway 0 and null?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException {

        ArrayList<Cart> list = new ArrayList<Cart>();

        Register store = new Register(1);
        store.setType(1);
        store.setList(list);

        Product first = new Product("Burger");
        Product second = new Product("Banana");

        Cart cart1 = new Cart(1);
        cart1.setType(1);
        cart1.addElement(first);
        cart1.addElement(second);
        store.getCartList().add(cart1);


        // create JAXB context and instantiate marshaller
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Register.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        // Write to System.out
        m.marshal(store, System.out);


            m.marshal(store, new File("mrs.xml"));

            System.out.println("Output from our XML File: ");
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Register reg = (Register) um.unmarshal(new FileReader("mrs.xml"));
            ArrayList<Cart> list1 = reg.getCartList();
            for(Cart x:reg.getCartList()) {
                System.out.println(x.getId());
            }
            for (Cart cart : list1) {
                System.out.println("Cart: " + cart.getId());
                for(Product product : cart.getCart()) {
                     System.out.println("Product: " + product.getProduct());
                }
            }


        }



}
```

So here is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CashRegister>
    <ShoppingCart CartIdentifier="1">
        <CurrentProducts productName="Burger"/>
        <CurrentProducts productName="Banana"/>
    </ShoppingCart>
</CashRegister>
Output from our XML File: 
0
Cart: 0
Product: null
Product: null
```

There is one cart with two products but not with 0 and null.

No, my question isn't duplicate. I don't want to have that as Element or show the name of that element in my xml. My xml looks perfect but i can't unmarshal it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CashRegister>
    <ShoppingCart CartIdentifier="1">
        <CurrentProducts productName="Burger"/>
        <CurrentProducts productName="Banana"/>
    </ShoppingCart>
</CashRegister>
Output from our XML File: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: bonusxml.Register cannot be cast to bonusxml.Register1
    at bonusxml.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

Comment: @user7294900 no check my edit

Comment: @user7294900 please don't suggest that this is duplicate because it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hell bent on preserving your XML structure, you will have to pay a price for that. Below, are classes that can get you de-serializing the XML you have created. But, you will end up using two different set of classes for serializing and de-serializing.

**Cart.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ShoppingCart")
public class Cart1 {

    @XmlElement(name = "CurrentProducts")
    private List<Product1> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    @XmlAttribute(name="CartIdentifier")
    private long CartIdentifier;

    public Cart1() {}

    public Cart1(long id) {
        this.CartIdentifier=id;
    }
    // setters & getters
}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product1 {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "productName")
    private String name;

    public Product1() {
    }

    public Product1(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
    // setters & getters
}
```

**Register.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CashRegister")
public class Register1 {

    @XmlElement(name = "ShoppingCart")
    private ArrayList<Cart1> listCart;

    long CartIdentifier;

    public Register1() {

    }

    public Register1(long id) {
        this.CartIdentifier=id;
    }
    //setters & getters
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, it solves part of my problem but still for output now i get  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CashRegister>
    <ShoppingCart CartIdentifier="1">
        <CurrentProducts productName="Burger"/>
        <CurrentProducts productName="Banana"/>
        <cart productName="Burger"/>
        <cart productName="Banana"/>
    </ShoppingCart>
</CashRegister>
Output from our XML File: 
1
Cart: 1
Product: Burger
Product: Banana

Comment: Yes, I have already mentioned, you can use your classes to generate the XML. You can only use these classes to unmarshall the XML, and not generate.

Comment: Oh okay. I will try to do it and than I will go back to you. @soufrk

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. I always get Register cannot be cast to Register 1 @soufrk What should I do?

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException @soufrk

Comment: Do note that your source XML has got changed. Did you try with your old XML ? Generate the XML with your classes and deserailize with these classes.

Comment: I have updated how my xml file looks like and also added the error that comes, xml is the old one

Comment: I have used my old POJO to create XML and yours to convert from XML to 'normal' output but this cast exception always comes up :/ @soufrk

Comment: I have found my mistake. I should create two different JAXBcontexts. Thank you for helping me! @soufrk

Comment: Can you upvote my question or something like that so I can accept your answer because I don't have reputation to do that.

Comment: Please use a suitable description and title for your question, which will help establish why you required this approach and answer.

Comment: Still not enough reputation... -.-